# How to get all indices of NumPy array, but not in a format provided by np.indices()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I would like to get all indices of 3x2 array using a NumPy function, produced in the same format, as `[[x, y] for x, y in np.ndindex((3, 2))]`:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1]]
```

The closest I found is `np.indices((3, 2))`, which produces an array requiring some transformations to get there:

```
[[[0 0]
  [1 1]
  [2 2]]

 [[0 1]
  [0 1]
  [0 1]]]
```

Is there another option with a single NumPy function call?

Comment: do you mean that nested items are an array instead of a tuple?

Comment: so `[*np.ndindex(3, 2)]` isn't fine?

Comment: Or `list(np.ndindex(3, 2))`

Comment: @GiladGreen Yes, as shown on the example. I want to be able to use elements of that array for indexing into 3x2 array.

Comment: @PaulJurczak You can use `x, y = np.indices((3, 2))` you index your array like this `your_array[x, y]`

Comment: @MustafaAydın `[*np.ndindex(3, 2)]` is fine.

Comment: @Ivan `list(np.ndindex(3, 2))` works too.

Comment: `np.ndindex` is a generator, and all these suggestions, including the OP, expand it to a list.  There are other ways of generating the same values, `np.ndindex`, `np.mgrid` but they need a bit of reshaping.  That shouldn't be a big deal except for that arbitrary **single** requirement.

Comment: Just for the fun of it, I'll throw out another one, `np.argwhere(np.ones((3,2)))`.  Under the cover it does a `np.transpose`.

Comment: @hpaulj *expand it to a list* - I need a list, np.array really, to make further operations on. *need a bit of reshaping* - wouldn't that incurr higher cost of element access?

Comment: Tweaking the layout of `np.indices` doesn't add much time.  Do your own time tests if you aren't convinced.  I often use time tests to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reshape and transpose it. np.ndindex() returns an array of shape (dims, input_shape). This can be done as follows

```
import numpy as np
your_req_in = np.indices((3, 2)).reshape(2,-1).T
```

Comment: The above way does not create new data

Comment: ...but use 2 more functions

Comment: @cards so what? It is faster than unpacking operator and does not create any excess memory. you can check how inefficient unpacking operator when you increase dimentions

Comment: no complain about your answer but on the restriction of the question "with a single NumPy function call"

Comment: @cards, but does the OP really want a "single call", or is he really more interested in speed?

Comment: @ hpaulj I understood it as follow: if it were possible to accomplish the task in a single function... you know with some hidden numpy-combo, maybe with `np.fromfunction`, `np.fromstring`, ... . He already pointed out a solution and asking for alternatives. This is my interpretation.