# How many columns/rows in this array?

Tags: python, numpy

I know this is probably a stupid question (bare with me please).
When I print out an array that has a shape (2, 493, 452), there should be 2 rows right? How come it looks like multiple rows below (e.g. first row is [ 0 0 0...0 0 0]) And then for the second output (2, 222836), this means there are 2 rows and 222836 columns?

```
(2, 493, 452)
[[[  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
  [  1   1   1 ...   1   1   1]
  [  2   2   2 ...   2   2   2]
  ...
  [490 490 490 ... 490 490 490]
  [491 491 491 ... 491 491 491]
  [492 492 492 ... 492 492 492]]

 [[  0   1   2 ... 449 450 451]
  [  0   1   2 ... 449 450 451]
  [  0   1   2 ... 449 450 451]
  ...
  [  0   1   2 ... 449 450 451]
  [  0   1   2 ... 449 450 451]
  [  0   1   2 ... 449 450 451]]]
(2, 222836)
[[  0   0   0 ... 492 492 492]
 [  0   1   2 ... 449 450 451]]
```

This is my code:

```
original_image=cv2.imread("mickey mouse.jpg")
img=cv2.cvtColor(original_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
vectorized=img.reshape((-1,3))
#print(vectorized.shape)
#print(vectorized)
ind=np.indices((m,n))
print(ind.shape)
print(ind)

ind.resize((2,m*n))
print(ind.shape)
print(ind)
```

Comment: It's not a matrix, it's a tensor... so there are three dimesions... width, height and depth

Comment: When you check the `[ ]`, then it makes sense.

Comment: I prefer to call the first dimension 'plane' or 'block', and only use row/columns for the last 2 dimensions.  But names like this are just for our human convenience.  They aren't part of the `numpy` code or documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`indices` makes 'indices' for each of the 2 dimensions:

```
ind=np.indices((m,n))
print(ind.shape)
print(ind)
```

So the result is a (2,m,n) array.  `ind[9,:,:]` are indices for the first demension, an (m,n) array.

Actually this should be `reshape`, but it makes (2, m*n) shape array from the original `ind`.

```
ind.resize((2,m*n))
print(ind.shape)
print(ind)
```

Rows/columns does not make a whole lot of sense when talking about these index arrays.

Look at a smaller case (from another recent SO, [How to get all indices of NumPy array, but not in a format provided by np.indices()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69324752/how-to-get-all-indices-of-numpy-array-but-not-in-a-format-provided-by-np-indice))

```
In [71]: list(np.ndindex(3,2))
Out[71]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
In [72]: np.indices((3,2))
Out[72]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])
```

`meshgrid` does the same thing, but as a list of 2 arrays:

```
In [75]: np.meshgrid(np.arange(3),np.arange(2),indexing='ij')
Out[75]: 
[array([[0, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2]]),
 array([[0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a numpy array with shape `(2, 493, 452)` and you print it out on the console, numpy will print it like it is 2 arrays with shape `(493, 452)`. This threw me off for a long time. Perhaps you might be thinking about the original array like 452 arrays of shape `(2, 493)`, in which case you might expect the console output to differ.

The shape will always be given by `arr.shape` even if the console output does not match what you expect.